# Why would Computer Vision recognize more text when submitting a subset of the image?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr

So I am attempting to use Azure Computer Vision OCR to recognize text in a jpg image.  The image is about 2000x3000 pixels and is a picture of a contract.  I want to get all the text and the bounding boxes.  The image DPI is over 300 and it's quality is very clear.  I noticed that a lot of text was being skipped so I cropped a section of the image and submitted that instead.  This time it recognized text that it did not recognize before.  Why would it do this?  If the quality of the image never changed and the image was within the bounds of the resolution requirements, why is it skipping texts?

Comment: by cropping the document to one single section, you're making the problem easier for the OCR software: you constrain the area where text may occur. Therefore, do as much preprocessing as possible, then the OCR software is only concerned with its main task, namely OCR.

Comment: @NicEndo yes it does

Comment: @Harry Do you recommend we split the image into as many smaller ones as possible then?  Or when you say preprocessing do you just mean cleaning the image?

Comment: if you are able to split the document into separate parts (without introducing errors), then I would give it a try.

Comment: @NicEndo I'm seeing that as well